# .ssh does not existe after creat a key

Tags: security, unix, ssh, ssh-keygen

When i run ssh-keygen,i have step by step creat a key with a PASSWORD. It tell me my key it's in

```
/var/root/.ssh/id_rsa/"mykey"
```

But when I locate the /var/root/.ssh with sudo or simple account it's not existing

I don't understhund who show directly in folder my passworded ssh key

I can juste show .ssh folder in user profile on /user/profilname/.ssh and it show the non-protegeds ssh keys.

locate
ssh-add
ssh-keygen -p

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-keygen` supports `-f` to specify the filename, so you can use it

> ```
>  -f filename
>         Specifies the filename of the key file.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,when I run ssh-keygen as root. This makes it a key in `/var/root/.ssh`
When I run it in non-root user .ssh it does it here `/Users/name/.ssh`

-f filename is used to directly indicate the name of the key to be created. But it shows with the tab all the existing keys with the same first letter indicated.

But i have again the incapacity to find the newest key in .ssh.
.ssh not creating